# MongoDb Handle Multiple Document Insert?

Tags: mongodb

I am new to Mongodb lets say i need to insert `3 documents` in  3 different `collections` for example lets say i have a `department`, `students` and  `department_membership` collections. when department head add one `student` to the `department` , so that time i need insert document like

> { _id: 123, name: "st_name", email: "test@gmail.com"  }

in `student` collection,

> {  _id: 2356, dept_id: 12 , added_by_whom_id: 253, student_id: 123}

in `department` collection

> { _id: 13111, dept_id: 12, student: { _id: 123, name: "st_name"  } }

in `department membership` collection

what i want is to either  insert all documents in respective collections or it should fail, how to handle this?

Comment: The "point" is that you don't. Instead you "should" be modelling so all "related" data is in the "one" collection, and likely one document. That's why you choose an document oriented storage system. If that doesn't suit, then you use a relational database with transactions. Horses for courses as they say.

Comment: ok, is it possible to do with [two phase commit](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits) ??

Comment: You want a relational database. You probably should really only be choosing MongoDB when you understand why you want it.